# Fetching One to Many object in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've the following two entities,

User

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class User extends BaseEntity{

  @Getter @Setter
  private String msid;
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "sender")
  @Getter
  private List<Media> sentList;
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "receiver")
  @Getter
  private List<Media> receivedList;

  protected User(){
    super();
  }

  public User(String yguid) {
    this();
    this.yguid = yguid;
    this.receivedList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.sentList = new ArrayList<>();
  }
}
```

Media

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Media extends BaseEntity{

  @Getter @Setter
  private String mediaId;
  @Getter @Setter
  private String url;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="sender")
  @Getter @Setter
  private User sender;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="receiver")
  @Getter @Setter
  private User receiver;

  public Media() {
   super();
  }

  public Media(String mediaId, String url, User sender, User receiver) {
    this();
    this.mediaId = mediaId;
    this.url = url;
    this.sender = sender;
    this.receiver = receiver;
  }
}
```

Both inherit from a BaseEntity

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private final Long id;

  public BaseEntity() {
    id = null;
  }
}
```

I want to fetch all Media for an user. This is my code

```
public List<Media> getReceivedMediaForUser(User user){
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Media m WHERE m.receiver = :user");
    //parse query to get result
    session.close();
    //
    return null;
  }
```

This doesn't compile, can someone help me form the right query and get the results. I'm new to Spring and Hibernate.

Comment: what is the compile error? Also you are not setting the `:user` parameter

Comment: Could you please add specific error you get . Is this a code compilation error or the query parsing fails during the runtime ?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as shown below (It is an example to follow not solution. Implement solution accordingly you requirements  ),

```
 Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
"select * from stock s where s.stock_code = :stockCode")
.addEntity(Stock.class)
.setParameter("stockCode", "7277");
List result = query.list();
```

Your solution could be

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("select * FROM Media m WHERE m.receiver = :user")
   .addEntity(Media.class)
   .setParameter("user", "xyz");
    List result = query.list();
    session.close();
```

Comment: This does not solve OP's problem..its not even close

Comment: @Akshay he didnt set :user param which is causing compilation error. In my example I have shown him how to add entity. he is new in spring & hibernate so it is very possibility that he might not know how to add entity and how to use hql.